# With the recent YouTube changes, is there anyway to post a reply to a comment via the API or some other method?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-api, google-plus

First off, thank you all for your time and help.

Basically before the recent changes to YouTube, I was working with the YouTube API on a website that would allow users to reply to comments from my own website. Before the changes this was available through the YouTube Data API version 2.0. My question is, is there any way to still do this? A quick search on Google leads me to believe this is no longer possible (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments).

However my understanding is with the new YouTube changes a user needs a Google+ account to reply to comments (I'm pretty ignorant on this subject, so please correct me if I'm wrong). **I was wondering if the Google+ API had a way to reply to YouTube comments**.

Or if anyone else knows a way to reply to a YouTube comment from another website, please let me know!

Thank you!

Comment: There is not currently a Google+ API to to post comments that will work for this. I'm not familiar enough with the YouTube API to know if there is on that side.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm pretty sure the YouTube API currently doesn't support it, but was unsure of the Google+ API.

Answer (score 0):

"replying directly to comments via the YouTube API is no longer supported. At this time, there's no way of replying to a new-style comment via the YouTube API." [[Link]](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments#threading)

EDIT: It is not possible at the current time, though they are bring out a new messaging API "later this year".